# Draw Bitmap instead of Rect

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

For Andriod I have this code:

```
public Tank(int color) {
    bounds = new RectF();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    bounds.set(x - radius, y - radius, x + radius, y + radius);
    canvas.drawRect(bounds, paint);
}
```

where I am drawing a Rect, but now I want to draw a Bitmap instead of a Rect, but

```
bitTank = BitmapFactory.decodeRescource(getRescource(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

or

```
bitTank = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\Users\...\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png");
```

(both) in combination with

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitTank, matrix, null);
```

is not working.

The first does not know `getRescource()` and with the second one it doesn't work anymore. How can I realize that? (The Code is in the class Tank and another class calls the draw function).

Comment: Thanks for editing, it didn't work when I tried to format it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version simply cannot work, because you are trying to access a file on your PC from the inside Android app.  Android doesn't know anything about your local PC.

With the first code, you need an instance of `Context` to access resources.  You can pass a context into your constructor and then use it:

```
class Tank {
    Context context;
    ...

    public Tank(int color, Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;

        bounds = new RectF();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...
        bitTank = BitmapFactory.decodeRescource(context.getRescources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ...
    }
}
```

While this is not the only way to achieve what you're after, it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It's `getResources()` with an 's' on the end.
Also make sure that you have a context to get the resources from. If you do the call from within your `Tank` class, you need to access the context in another way, either as `YourActivity.this` if `Tank` is an inner class an activity, or pass it in the constructor otherwise:

```
public Tank(Context ctx, int color) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //... other loading

}
```